# Downcast from AnyObject?

Tags: swift, downcast

I am a bit puzzled as to what is going on with the code below. I was under the impression that `children` would be an optional based on `node.children` (which is of type `[AnyObject]`) being of type `[SKNode]` What I am seeing is that `children` is never `nil`, is this because `[AnyObject]` does not contain any type information? Even if I change `[SKNode]` to `[NSString]` it still goes to (1)?

```
    if let children = node.children as? [SKNode] {
        // (1) STUFF WITH SKNODE...
    } else {
        // (2) NOPE, ITS NOT AN SKNODE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node.children` is not an optional.  It always returns an array of type `[AnyObject]`.  If there are no children, this array will have 0 elements.  If there are children, then this array will contain `SKNode`s.

The optional binding `if let children = node.children as? [SKNode]` will always succeed because an empty array of objects `[AnyObject]` can be cast to `[SKNode]`.

When I first saw that `node.children` was returning `[AnyObject]` instead of `[SKNode]` I thought that was odd.  Then I realized that this is a `Cocoa Touch` interface that works with `Objective-C` so it isn't going to be able to return `[SKNode]` even though that is what it contains.

Comment: I see, thats because of the AnyObject bit. If you look in the docs it says that node.children returns [AnyObject] (which will always be SKNodes apparently). Its funny how it always succeeds if you cast it to [NSString], I guess thats because AnyObject also covers NSString objects too.

Comment: It only succeeds when you cast it to `[NSString]` when it is empty.  If there were any `SKNode`s in the array, the cast would not happen.

Comment: yup perfect, I get it, I was forgetting about the fact that it can empty. Much appreciated Sir, thank you for your time.